# SQL: count entries that are close to each others time

Tags: sql, date, compare

I'm trying to create a query that counts each time a task is added within 7 days of the previous time a task was created for the same piece of equipment.

We have service requests that can have multiple service tasks. Each task can have a piece of service equipment linked to it.

Here's the code as I have it so far. My results end up counting all service tasks minus one instead of just the ones that are within 7 days of a previous task and I'm not sure why. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, 
e.strSerialNumber, 
COUNT(r2.dtmServiceRequestStartDate) 
as 'Call-Backs'

FROM tblServiceRequest r2
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblServiceTask t2
ON r2.lngServiceRequestID = t2.lngServiceRequestID
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblServiceEquipment e
ON e.lngSEID = t2.lngSEID
INNER JOIN tblCustomers c
ON r2.strShipTo = c.CustomerID

WHERE r2.dtmServiceRequestStartDate < (
 SELECT MAX(r.dtmServiceRequestStartDate)
 FROM tblServiceRequest r
 LEFT OUTER JOIN tblServiceTask t
 ON r.lngServiceRequestID = t.lngServiceRequestID
 WHERE r.dtmServiceRequestStartDate < (
  SELECT MAX(dtmServiceRequestStartDate) 
  FROM tblServiceRequest r1 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tblservicetask t1 
  ON r1.lngServiceRequestID = t1.lngServiceRequestID 
  WHERE t.lngSEID = t1.lngSEID)
) + 7
AND t2.lngSEID IS NOT NULL
AND c.Active = 1
GROUP BY c.CustomerID, e.strSerialNumber
```

Comment: Welcome to [so], for `sql` related question, please state the DBMS you are using (sql server, oracle ... etc).  And please also provide the table structure, sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the `DATEDIFF` 
function. Example from the MSDN:

```
USE AdventureWorks; GO SELECT DATEDIFF(day, OrderDate, GETDATE()) AS NumberOfDays FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader; GO
```

Comment: How do you know OP is using a dbms supporting that product specific function?